# Matlab False-Position Method

Tags: matlab, iteration

I am currently working on a homework assignment that asks me to estimate a value using the false-position method. I feel that I have almost everything there, but I am getting hung up on my if statement.  So I have to determine the posotive real root of the function : ln(x^2)=0.7 using the false postion method with 3 iterations, xl = 0.5 and xu=2.  I have attached the correct answers on the bottom to help me better explain my questions.  I have three specific questions in which I need help.

1). Firstly, in the third iteration for the value of Xl my code is still treating it as 1.625 instead of the correct 1.25.  I dont understand why it is doing this as my if statement should be preventing this.  It is correctly changing that value in the second iteration just not the third.

2).  I also need help in finding the error. This part I am pretty stuck on.  I know the equation to find the error but my question is how to keep track of what is xr_new and xr_old.  Im not sure if I want to add somekind of compare to see if it changes before calculating or what.

3).  I would also like to output my value and build a table like the solution provided.  My previous experience with table is hard-coding the values directly into it and I'm having a difficult time building the table when values are found. I know I need the table in the for loop and I build it one cell at a time, but just dont have experience in this field to get started.

I hope this isn't too much help to ask for I have intermiate matlab skills and this is one of the harder questions I have had to do. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

```
clc; clear;
f= @(x) log(x.^2) - 0.7;
x = -3: .005 : 3;
figure(1)
grid on
hold on
plot (x,f(x))

% bisection method with 3 iterations
xl = 0.5
xu = 2

%Table = table(iteration, xl , f(xl), xu, f(xu), xr, f(xr), Ea) 

for i = 1:1:3

    F_xl = f(xl)
    F_xu = f(xu)
    xr = .5*(xl+xu)
    F_xr = f(xr)

    if ((F_xu*F_xl) < 0)
        xl = xr

    else
      xu = xr
    end


    %Error = abs(xr_new-xr_old)/xr_new
end
```

[image: The correct soluton displayed in a table below:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gives the desired output, and is preceded by your code until the `plot()`

1. The `if` condition failed as you used `F_xl` instead of `F_xr`. `if ((F_xu*F_xr) < 0)` gives the desired result.
2. We can use a vector for `xr` to store the values of `xr` in each iteration and use the expression `abs(xr_new-xr_old)/xr_new)` to find the error. I just left the first error value to be zero.
3. Since we have vectors, `table()` can be used outside the loop to get the desired output

Code:

```
iterations = (1:3)';
xl = zeros(3,1);
xu = zeros(3,1);
xr = zeros(3,1);
F_xl = zeros(3,1);
F_xu = zeros(3,1);
F_xr = zeros(3,1);
Error = zeros(3,1);
% bisection method with 3 iterations
xl(1) = 0.5;
xu(1) = 2;
for i = 1:3
    F_xl(i) = f(xl(i));
    F_xu(i) = f(xu(i));
    xr(i) = .5*(xl(i)+xu(i));
    F_xr(i) = f(xr(i));
    if(i<3)
        if ((F_xu(i)*F_xr(i)) < 0)
          xl(i+1) = xr(i);
          xu(i+1) = xu(i);
        else
          xu(i+1) = xr(i);
          xl(i+1) = xl(i);
        end
    end
    if(i>1)
        Error(i) = abs(xr(i)-xr(i-1))*100/xr(i);
    end
end
T = table(iterations,xl,F_xl,xu,F_xu,xr,F_xr,Error);
```

Comment: I have no idea why the line iterations= (1:3)'; is not within the code. Add that line when you try this code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should've thought to start xl, xu, and xr as 3 empty spaces.

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully, you understood what's being done in the code. I didn't explain much as you said you are an experienced MATLAB programmer.